# Is the visible property of controls in c sharp localizable?

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I've been trying to make a user control that suport two languages (using localization) and in the default language I have a control that his visible property is False and in the other language I change it to True but still in run time I couldnt see it in both languages.
What should I do?
The visible propery of controls suports localization?!
Plz help me.
BTW, I program in C#.

Comment: What sort of control is it? Why do you want to display a control in one language and not another?

Answer (score 3):

No, `Visible` isn't a localizable property. So you probably have to have some piece of custom code which hides/shows some controls depending on the UI culture.