# How to detect localizable properties in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

[Somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748387/is-the-visible-property-of-controls-in-c-sharp-localizable), someone states that the "Visible" Property of a control cannot be localized. This is half-true. However, the "Visible" Property has the LocalizableAttribute set to true. But this just means that the property is serialized to the resource file. I wrote a test program that has the visible property of a label set to "false" for the Invariant Culture. Making the form localizable I changed the visible property to "true" for the German culture. Now what happens if I start the program with the system set to German locale? The label stays invisible. 
Checking the resource file Form1.de.resx I can see that the visible property has not been serialized. But if I manually add this to the resource file:

```
<data name="label1.Visible" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
  <value>True</value>
</data>
```

the label appears. I confess to be slightly confused.
Two questions:

- How can I detect if a property is "truly" localizable using the build-in serializer?
- What is the recommended way to override the default behaviour?

---

**Edit**:
Maybe I need to clarify my question. 
My sample program is a simple form which has the default language set to invariant. I have manually added german resources through the forms designer. Program runs on a system with regional settings set to german.

Case 1

"**Visible**" Property of a panel added to the form:
    1.) set to false in Invariant culture, true (default) in german culture. => panel is invisible
    2.) set to true in Invariant culture, false in german culture. => panel is invisible (works as expected)
Apparently the value is only written to the language specific resource file if it's not the default.

Case 2

"**Font**" Property of a label added to the form:
    1.) set to bold in Invariant culture, Property is reset to default in german culture. => label is not bold
    2.) set to default in Invariant culture, bold in german culture. => label is bold
Now here the properties are serialized as expected.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: We have filed this as a bug with MS support. The support engineer has confirmed it. I'll let you know how this goes on.. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have received a response from Microsoft:

> I can see that this can be a problem
>   for this localization scenario, but in
>   general case, this is the way to
>   greatly reduce the size of a resx
>   file, so we would not want to change
>   this implementation.  This design flaw
>   does not meet our current bar, so this
>   will not be fixed in the next release.

So the answer is: There is currently no solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine when I try it.  Steps taken to test:

- drop a TextBox on the form
- set the form's Localizable property to True
- set the form's Language to Afrikaans
- set the TextBox' Visible property to True
- modified the constructor like this:

  ```
  public Form1() {
      System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("af");
      InitializeComponent();
  }
  ```

The text box isn't visible when I run the form.  I comment out the CurrentUICulture assignment to switch back to English: text box is visible.

Comment: Try the opposite. Have it be visible when the culture is Afrikaans and not visible when its the default (English).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Microsoft would classify this as a bug. It's working as designed; but it definitely is a pain in the neck.

There's not an easy solution that I'm aware of short of sub-classing the Label control and adding properties - yuck.

As a workaround, could you simply set the Width or Text properties instead of the Visibility?

Answer (score 0):

I still believe that the Visible property is not localizable. It is always reset to its setting for the default language when I switch to the default laguage and then back to the specific language, does not matter whether it is a default setting or not.

Comment: If you try Case 1 Number 2, you will see that an entry for the "Visible" property is generated for the specific language. So it's localizable... sort of. :)

Comment: Yes, you are write... But this definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: When you reset the font in a specific language to not bold, it is still shown as changed in the Properties window. This is probably the reason why it is serialized.